# How to use the older version of ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I have been using rvm and when I installed ruby 1.9.2, it installed ruby-1.9.2-p290 and a few days back I wasn't able to reference the older one but it asked to install ruby-1.9.2-p318.

Is it mandatory to move to the newer version or would it be possible for us to instruct rvm to use the gemset created with the older version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the RVM commands, such as `rvm install` and `rvm use`, can take a patchlevel, e.g.: `rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p290`. If you don't specify one, the latest available patchlevel will be used.

Answer (score 6):

What brandon said is correct also you may want to set up a default ruby version with the --default flag. This will ensure that you are using the same version every time when you start up your terminal.

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290 --default
```

You may also want to set up a .rvmrc file in the directory you are working in to ensure that other developers are using the same ruby version and patch level as you are.

```
touch .rvmrc && echo "rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290" >> .rvmrc
```